# SLF4J writes to file, but not to eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, slf4j

I am using slf4j for logging and Glassfish as app server. 
My logback.xml

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>C:\glassfish4\glassfish\logs\log.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{52} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
    <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger level="DEBUG" name="ru.vmakarenko"/>
<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

My logging.properties

```
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.level=INFO
handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
javax.enterprise.system.ssl.security.level=INFO
org.apache.jasper.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency=1
org.eclipse.persistence.session.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.tools.backup.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.corba.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.resource.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jta.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.saaj.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.level=INFO
org.glassfish.naming.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.level=INFO
org.apache.catalina.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes=0
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.mdb.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=false
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.excludeFields=
org.apache.coyote.level=INFO
ShoalLogger.level=CONFIG
javax.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.taglib.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.rpc.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.javamail.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=true
javax.enterprise.system.container.web.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.util.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.level=ALL
javax.org.glassfish.persistence.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jms.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.multiLineMode=true
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=2000000
javax.enterprise.system.core.config.level=INFO
org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.security.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.cmp.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=false
javax.enterprise.resource.sqltrace.level=FINE
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit.level=INFO
handlerServices=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.registry.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.alarms=false
javax.enterprise.system.core.selfmanagement.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=0
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.validator.util.Version=warn
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean.level=INFO
org.glassfish.admingui.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jdo.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours=0
```

And domain.xml (jvm-options)

```
<jvm-options>-Djava.util.logging.config.file=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/logging.properties</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/logback.xml</jvm-options>
```

So i get the C:\glassfish4\glassfish\logs\log.log file with all logged stuff I need.
But I get nothing at Eclipse Console. I have Glassfish Tools installed, and server is managed from eclipse. What is my mistake, how can i redirect output both to file and console?

Also, when I run maven, I get

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Maybe it's part of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in the console processing of the Eclipse GlassFish Tools plugin, check [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2574307) thread and [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-374) related bug report.

I have a similar problem - I can't get the JUL logging to work properly. If I set the logging level of my application class to anything lower than CONFIG, nothing is logged to the Eclipse console, but it is also still logged to server.log. Also, if I start the GlassFish server outside of Eclipse, I do get all my FINE level messages printed on the terminal.

**UPDATE:**
I could finally make log entries with a level below CONFIG work by using a thin wrapper which for example calls `Logger.logp(Level.FINE, null, null, msg)`. GlassFish Tools apparently can't handle the format produced by `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter` for levels FINE and lower, which includes additional CLASSNAME and METHODNAME fields, so setting the source explicitly to `null` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using log4j, then declares slf4j log4j binding too in your pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

or if you are not using log4j then make sure you have all the below dependency into your pom.xml file :

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please check the answer, above dependency is for logback only. It is  not for log4j.